# Currently using a listbox, populated from an arraylist with multiple 'values'. Is there a better way?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, google-maps

**Goal:**

Populate an asp `ListBox` with city names on submit button click (button click calls a sql proc that returns an arraylist with multiple arrays within that contain`{Name, Zip, Pop, Lat, Lng}`

On front end `ListBox` item click, it takes `Name, Zip, Pop, Lat, Lng` and displays them in separate textboxes.  It then takes the `Lat` and `Lng` and redirects the map.

**Currently:**

Initially, my thought was to add each item to the listbox via loop, and then pass the whole array over via serialization and `Json.parse()` and match the `OnClick index` with the `arraylist index` but doing so would cause the procedure to load on every button click, whether I wanted it to run or not.  This is an issue since the procedure takes much longer than the other ones I have.

So now, I'm fumbling around with this `ListBox` and I'm wondering if there's a better way to do what I want to do.  I've tried using a structure for each of the cities and assigning `DisplayMember` with the name but I realized I'd have to throw the rest all mashed up together in the `Value` which I'd like to avoid.  Not to mention I'm getting a 'DisplayMember' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Listbox' error.

I'm all for not using this listbox if there's a better way of doing this in terms of programming design and maintainability.

Comment: `better way` in terms of what? Performance ? Programming Design? Maintainability? User Experience? ....

Comment: Programming Design and maintainability.

Comment: Its difficult for people who want to help you, to actually help you without you posting your code. I would also have thought that if your question is a web related one, then you load the list into an array at the FORM_LOAD event, no need to reload it again on every mouse/button click. And if your question is about a form (win-forms) then you load your array again in the FORM_LOAD event and access it from anywhere later on without reloading it over and over. its all to do with SCOPE and where you scope your ARRAY